# How do I upgrade Apache 2.2.25 to 2.2.xx on my Centos instance?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I have a Centos instance with Apache 2.2.25 installed on it as part of the LAMP stack. All I want to do is upgrade to Apache 2.2.xx. I cannot use yum to do this because it asks me to update Apache to 2.4.xx which is not what I want.

What are the commands I need to run to get the Apache 2.2.xx version and how do I install it?

Centos version: centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64

Results of rpm -qa | grep httpd:  httpd-2.2.25-1.x86_64

Comment: Which CentOS version you use?

Comment: And please give result of `rpm -qa | grep httpd`

Comment: @AlexanderT, I updated the summary above.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent about an hour trying to find a distro you could add to your yum that carries httpd 2.2.x but no such luck.
One other alternative would be a fresh install of httpd 2.2.31 by building it yourself from source.
You can find it here: http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/

**Downloading the source:**

```
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.31.tar.gz
```

**Building the source**

```
tar zxvf httpd-2.2.31.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.31.tar.gz
./configure --enable-so --enable-rewrite=shared
make
make install
```

I really don't recommend this as it isn't what you originally asked for. Of course, it is an option though so I thought I'd throw it out there for you anyway. Be sure to back up your current apache configuration if you are to take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the answer should be pretty timeless:

If you can at all, my recommendation would be to keep servers and software up-to-date and in the state recommended by the distribution managers.

The alternative if there are no supported and trusted third-party repositories for the software version you need to run, is to compile your version from sources. Note that this puts the burden of keeping your software patched on you, which will likely be untenable in the long run, especially for Internet-facing services.